# Are the terms 'pipeline' and 'life cycle' the same in the context of an MVC framework?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, model-view-controller, asp.net-web-api2

In CakePHP the term 'life cycle' of an MVC framework is known to me as a chain of method invocations between an http request and response. There is an MSDN article about REST and Web API in ASP.NET Core written by Dino Esposito: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt845654. He often uses the word 'pipeline'.

Question: Are the terms 'pipeline' and 'life cycle' the same in the context of an MVC framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the ASP.NET world (and that article), "pipeline" refers to the HTTP server plus the middleware stack that handles incoming and outgoing requests (rewriting, authentication, routing and so on). This is usually up and running independent of an individual request (ignoring the special case of the first request that triggers start-up; after, for example, IIS has shut down an application pool due to something like idle-timeout).

"Lifecycle" is seen in several contexts, but it usually refers to either the start-to-finish processing of a specific request, or other subsystems such as the way services are registered for dependency injection.

Comment: as described in the Microsoft Documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/index?tabs=aspnetcore2x your answer seem to be correct.